# Excel macro to run data filter with current month values alone

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me with a macro script to run data filter for present month dates alone.

This should  happen for all the months.

---------I recorded this macro - manually filtering this month dates alone------

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_owssvr").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator _
        :=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "11/10/2017")
End Sub
```

In the above. **"11/10/2017" -** Instead of todays date - 
how to interpret in excel macro to get all november dates from the  following list for example:

```
9/27/2017
9/29/2017
10/2/2017
11/9/2017
11/10/2017
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter by this month

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_owssvr").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=xlFilterThisMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
```

Filter pivot table by month: Haven't tested this yet, but the idea is to add a filter.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(PivotTableName).PivotFields(fieldname).PivotFilters. _
    Add Type:=xlDateThisMonth
```

Comment: Great.. One more query..I have a pivot to pull out data from an sharepoint site which automatically refreshes count and shows the result.. Is there anyway I can use your macro script, so that the pivot filters the data and shows only present months count....